# MS Access combo box subform filter afterupdate

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a combo box, when I select a value, I would like the subform to filter on a particular field with that respective value.

I cannot figure out how to get the Macro Action Builder on After update to function correctly, so I am trying some vba in the afterupdate event field for the combo box. 
One line of code in the event field: "SELECT * FROM [fsubtotal] WHERE [Fund Codes] = " & cbo1.Column(0)

fsubtotal is my subform and Fund Codes is the Field I want to apply the filter to. I'm not sure if I should use 0 or 1 for Column(x), as 0 is the key ID in auto number format, but 1 would be the actual fund codes in short text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to link the subform to the combo box in question by selecting the subform container, and then in the property sheet, going to Data -> Link Master Fields.  The master field is whatever field you want to connect from the master form.

Comment: This is something that has confused me slightly. So the hierarchy seems to be as such: Main Form (contains combo box) -> 2 subforms (titles and funds). Link Master Fields in subforms: combo box? To apply the said filter to the subform, would that also go in a Link field, or just in the after_update field of the combo box event property tab? Thanks!

Comment: Master Field = the selection from your combo box.  Child Field = the field in your subform that you want to link to.  In example, if you select 'Red' from your combo box, then in your subform, you would set the child field as the one that relates to the 'Red' selection.

Comment: This seems to help. To be slightly more specific, in the Master Field, would I use say cbo1 (name of my combo box), or to be more specific, cbo1.Column(0 or 1). Similarly, Child Field, is that =[field].[subform]? Thanks again!

Comment: Master field should have a dropdown of all the fields in the main form, while child field should have a dropdown of all fields in the sub form.